# Findout the LDAP groups in which given uid is belong

Tags: java, ldap, ldap-query

I have a little bit knowledge of LDAP.
I have organozational structure in LDAP in below format,

**uid=test.gen,OU=Generics,O=cco.mycomp.com**

Above uid is part of group **"EF_GROUP"** and some other groups also.

Now i am only getting leaf note value in my method that is **"test.gen"**.

So my problem is that i want retrieve the all groups in which given uid is being belonging.

Please help me out.

Comment: Its our internal method for example, checkAccess(String uid){ // here i want find out all the groups in which given uid belong }

Comment: So did you have a look at e.g. [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/index.html)?

Comment: Ok.I will go through your link.

Answer (score 3):

An LDAP query of

`(&(objectClass=group)(memberof=YourUsersDNhere))`

would find them.  You should be allowed to specify a base DN that is where the groups ought to be located.  Which is nice as it also would scope the query a bit.

However, you will not have a memberUid attribute on the group in ADAM as you might in OpenLdap or the like, which would be an even easier search.  Though of course, you could maintain it and use that instead.  (MemberUid is usually just the shortname of the user vs the full DN that is usually in member).

Answer (score 1):

```
ldapsearch -xb 'dc=example,dc=com' '(&(cn=*)(memberUid=USER))'
```

where USER is the uid that you want to know about

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which directory server hosts your data, you could request the `memberOf` or `isMemberOf` attribute in your LDAP search request to determine to which groups a user belongs. The blog entry "[Using the groupOfUrls object class](https://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/using-the-groupofurls-object-class/)" has an example of this type of search.

Comment: Hi Terry, I am using ADAM(Microsoft Directory Server) as i have values of leaf node.I have to do the searching from bottom so i am not getting stuff how to search groups only using uid value.